# Flatten array of arrays (different dimensions) of a sql.dataframe.DataFrame in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` which is something like this:

```
+---------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|collect_list(results)      |        userid      |         page       |
+---------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|       [[[roundtrip, fal...|13482f06-9185-47f...|1429d15b-91d0-44b...|
+---------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Inside the collect_list(results) column there is an array with len = 2, and the elements are also arrays (the first one has a len = 1, and the second one a len = 9).

Is there a way to flatten this array of arrays into a unique array with len = 10 using pyspark?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it is easier to rework by altering the way you got to this DataFrame. Can you show us?

Comment: @OliverW. the query is pretty simple: `query1 = spark.sql("""

select collect_list(results), userid, page
from table
group by 2,3

""")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flatten an array of array using `pyspark.sql.functions.flatten`. Documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.flatten). For example this will create a new column called `results` with the flatten results assuming your dataframe variable is called `df`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
...
df.withColumn('results', F.flatten('collect_list(results)')
```

Comment: I've just realized I have version 2.3.1 and according to the documentation "flatten" is in version 2.4. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

For a version that works before Spark 2.4 (but not before 1.3), you could try to `explode` the dataset you obtained before grouping, thereby unnesting one level of the array, then call `groupBy` and `collect_list`. Like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, explode

df = spark.createDataFrame([("foo", [1,]), ("foo", [2, 3])], schema=("foo", "bar"))
df.show()
# +---+------+                                                                    
# |foo|   bar|
# +---+------+
# |foo|   [1]|
# |foo|[2, 3]|
# +---+------+
(df.select(
    df.foo,
    explode(df.bar))
 .groupBy("foo")
 .agg(collect_list("col"))
 .show())
# +---+-----------------+
# |foo|collect_list(col)|
# +---+-----------------+
# |foo|        [1, 2, 3]|
# +---+-----------------+
```